# Perl: basic question about hashmap

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

```
$hash_map{$key}->{$value1} = 1;
```

I'm just a beginner at perl and I need help in this expression, what does this expression mean? I assume that a new key/value pair will be created but what is the meaning of 1 here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've got here is a hash of hashes, or a two-level hash. `$hash_map{$key}` holds a hash reference, which points to another hash. `$hash_map{$key}{$value}` (the arrow can be omitted in this case) is a particular key in the second hash. The `1` is the value being assigned to that hash key.

For more on this topic, see [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES) section on Hashes of Hashes, and also see the [Perl reference tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for how references work.